# Почему отозванный голос не отображается на временной шкале?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, временная-шкала

В уведомлениях вижу -10:

[image: Скриншот уведомлений]

Ссылка ведёт на [ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627684/svg-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8/627736#627736) с +4 -0:

[image: Скриншот ответа]

Во [временной шкале](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/627736/timeline) тоже не вижу ничего интересного:

[image: Скриншот временной шкалы]

<s>Так что же именно произошло и где это можно увидеть?</s>

Нашёл на странице репутации - отозван голос за:

[image: Скриншот репутации]

**Тогда вопрос: почему отозванный голос не виден на временной шкале?**

Comment: А зачем ему храниться в timeline? Это действие, которого по сути не было

Comment: он похоже в ежедневные итоги попал: там же в итоге за:4 а не 5-1

Comment: @Grundy, но там же 14 февраля, а сегодня 22.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вот не знаю:)

Comment: Отображение репутации зависит от последовательности событий и их времени. В некоторых случаях отзыв голоса будет отображаться как корректировка (отрицательная репутация), в других исходная запись просто пропадет.